# Remove an anchor from querySelectorAll output

Tags: javascript

To get the book list from https://www.java67.com/2015/09/top-10-algorithm-books-every-programmer-read-learn.html , I am using the following code in the console of the firefox DevTools:

```
var select =  document.querySelectorAll("div.post-body.entry-content div h3 b");

for (i = 0; i < select.length; ++i) {
  var title =  select[i].querySelectorAll("u, a")[0];
  console.log (title.innerHTML);
}
```

The output is:

```
Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Corman
Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick &amp; Kevin Wayne
The Algorithm Design Manual by Steve S. Skiena
Algorithm for Interviews
5. Algorithm in Nutshell debugger eval code:5:13
6. Algorithm Design by Kleinberg &amp; Tardos debugger eval code:5:13
<a href="https://dev.to/javinpaul/10-best-books-to-learn-data-structure-and-algorithms-in-java-python-c-and-c-5743" target="_blank">7. Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach</a>
7. Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach debugger
8. The Design and Analysis of Algorithms debugger eval code:5:13
9. Data Structures and Algorithms. Aho, Ullman &amp; Hopcroft debugger eval code:5:13
10. Python Algorithms: Mastering Basic Algorithms in the Python Language debugger eval code:5:13
undefined
```

How can I remove

```
<a href="https://dev.to/javinpaul/10-best-books-to-learn-data-structure-and-algorithms-in-java-python-c-and-c-5743" target="_blank">7. Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach</a>
```

from the output.

I tried `console.log (title.firstChild.innerHTML);` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) returns the content of a node as HTML as it says.
Use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) to get rid of the HTML and just get its text.

Working example:

```
var select =  document.querySelectorAll("div.post-body.entry-content div h3 b");

for (i = 0; i < select.length; ++i) {
  var title =  select[i].querySelectorAll("u, a")[0];
  console.log (title.innerText);
}
```